# Reading a external XML file using __XPath(${__P(fileName)}

Tags: jmeter

I have a situation where in I am trying to read a node value of an external XML. I am using BeanShell sampler to read the fileName (passed via command line) and using setProperty method setting the value of the parsed node:

```
${__setProperty(variable_name,${__XPath(${__P(fileName)},/Allocations/item/@name)})}
```

Though the above method retrieves the value of the node I intended to receive, there is a error thrown:

> 2013/03/19 19:32:59 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: `` D:\myProject\Jmeter Tests\allocate.xml      ;'' Token Parsing Error: Lexical error at line 2, column 3.  Encountered: "\" (92), after : ""

My xml file looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Allocations>
    <item name="CAR" />
</Allocations>
```

Kindly advice if I am doing some error while reading.

Answer (score 0):

Very strange because looks you are doing everything correct.
I've reproduced your scenario step-by-step but works fine for me.

Try to use e.g. [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) / [Debug PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_PostProcessor) to monitor your jmeter properties and ensure that `fileName` normally set from command-line and doesn't contain any extra symbols.